# Aptana Studio: Following file links in terminal

Tags: linux, aptana-studio

I'm using Aptana Studio on a Ubuntu system for some Ruby on Rails programming.  When I run file-generating commands in the bash terminal provided by Aptana such as `rails g migration foo`, files are created and linked to in the terminal.

Clicking the links will open an editor, supposedly of the file.  However, this editor always shows a blank page, and is not the correct file that was just created.

The terminal-link-to-editor behavior works correctly on the OSX 10.7 machine I've tried it on.

How do I fix this?

I'm using `Aptana Studio 3, build 3.2.1.201207261642` on `ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit`.  Possibly less relevant, but I'm using `ruby 1.9.3-p194` and `rails 3.2.8`.

Comment: Could you run `ls -l linkedfile` (replacing 'linkedfile' with the actual file name) on the links?

Comment: @terdon the file names are shown relative to the root of the project, regardless of current directory within the project.

Comment: I was just thinking that that way you could check what the links are pointing to and whether the relevant files exist.

Comment: @terdon the files do exist in the indicated directory... I think aptana studio is using a different base path when following the relative link.